# I appear to be getting a recurring dependency, how do I fix this?

Tags: debian, dependencies, make

I am trying to install `make` - normally I just type `sudo apt-get install make` and it works, but on this server I am getting the following;

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
git-core: Depends: libdigest-sha1-perl but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: rcs but it is not going to be installed
```

Firstly, I don't fully understand what git-core has to do with anything, but for now I just want `make` to work so I ploughed on by running `apt-get -f install` but this fails for the same reason.

So I tried to install `libdigest-sha1-perl`, it fails because `rcs` is needed. So I go to install `rcs` and guess why it fails? Yup `libdigest-sha1-perl` is needed.

I have never come across this before and any pointers on how to achieve this would be greatly received.

The machine is running Debian 5.0.9 if that makes any odds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git-core doesn't have anything to do with make, but you are going to get this error for whatever you try to install - apt-get won't proceed if some dependencies are broken.

Try something of the following:

- try to reinstall git-core:
  `apt-get remove git-core`
  `apt-get update`
  `apt-get install git-core`
  Not sure about Debian 5, but since Debian 6 git-core is obsolete, so you should be installing package named `git` for the git version control system.
- or download make and install it with dpkg;